# Apply internationalization to a QString containing html

Tags: html, qt, internationalization, qstring

I need to create a `QString` that contains html. I want to internationalize it... adding `QObject::tr()`

How can I combine it ? At this point, my string is like this... I don't think I can apply `tr` to he entire string, or I'd end up with odd words for colors, text, size...

```
const QString errorContent = QObject::tr("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                           "<svg height=\"100\" width=\"80\">\n"
                           "<text font-size=\"20\" x=\"10\" y=\"30\" fill=\"black\">Unable</text>\n"
                           "<text font-size=\"20\" x=\"10\" y=\"60\" fill=\"black\">to load</text>\n"
                           "<text font-size=\"20\" x=\"20\" y=\"90\" fill=\"black\">SVG</text>\n"
                           "Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.\n"
                           "\n</svg>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply build the string from multiple `QStrings` where the `tr()` is only applied to the relevant part:

```
const QString errorContent = QString("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                       "<svg height=\"100\" width=\"80\">\n"
                       "<text font-size=\"20\" x=\"10\" y=\"30\" fill=\"black\">Unable</text>\n"
                       "<text font-size=\"20\" x=\"10\" y=\"60\" fill=\"black\">to load</text>\n"
                       "<text font-size=\"20\" x=\"20\" y=\"90\" fill=\"black\">SVG</text>\n")
                       + QObject::tr("Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG")
                       + QString(".\n\n</svg>");
```